# Guardar todos los items del carrito

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy buscando ayuda para este problema que tengo al momento de guardar mis items que agregue al carrito de compras, si agrego varios al carrito solo me guarda uno solo y el precio y la cantidad me guarda el total de todo como puedo hacer que me guarde todos los ids de los items y su la cantidad que le corresponde y su precio. Soy nuevo en esto si me pueden explicar detallado lo que tengo que modificar se los agradecería.

```
$nombre = $this->input->post('nombre');
$apellido = $this->input->post('apellido');
$nueva_insercionCliente = $this->catalogo_model->insertarCliente($nombre,$apellido);
$idCliente = $this->db->insert_id();
$carrito = $this->cart->contents();

foreach ($carrito as $item) {
    $idProducto = $item['id'];

    if ($item['id'] == $idProducto) {
        $cantidad = 1 + $item['qty'];
        $total =$item['price'] * $cantidad;
    }
}

$nueva_insercionPedido=$this->catalogo_model->insertarPedido($idProducto,$idCliente,$cantidad,$total);
redirect(base_url("catalogo"),"refresh");
```

Comment: Solo como comentario Diego, el if que tienes siempre se va a cumplir porque la condición la defines en la línea inmediatamente anterior, parece innecesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes de hacer es meter el `insert` dentro del `foreach` para que en cada iteración se inserte los datos que contiene tu carrito de compras. Quedando tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
$nombre = $this->input->post('nombre');
$apellido = $this->input->post('apellido');
$nueva_insercionCliente = $this->catalogo_model->insertarCliente($nombre,$apellido);
$idCliente = $this->db->insert_id();

$carrito = $this->cart->contents();

foreach ($carrito as $item) {
    $idProducto = $item['id'];
    $cantidad = 1 + $item['qty'];
    $total =$item['price'] * $cantidad;
    $nueva_insercionPedido=$this->catalogo_model->insertarPedido($idProducto,$idCliente,$cantidad,$total);
}
redirect(base_url("catalogo"),"refresh");
```

Solo te guardaba el primero por que es el que quedaba almacenado en cada una de tus variables.

Comment: Gracias le acabo de probar como tu me dijiste y me guarda todo pero al momento de que elimine redirect(base_url("catalogo"),"refresh");  la pagina me queda en blanco

Comment: Esa parte de tu codigo se queda solo te mostre la forma en que debes de interactuar en el foreach de hecho el if dentro del foreach esta demas deberias de quitarlo quedando el foreach como te lo muestro

Comment: Al momento que mando a guardar, si se me guardan ya todos los items pero mi pagina que en blanco que le puedo hacer para que eso no suceda porque no me sale ningun error

Comment: Ya puse el código completo como tu lo proporcionaste, ya no deberia de fallar

Comment: Gracias era el if el que me estaba dando problemas muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Para eso esta el foro si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aceptada..

Comment: amigo tengo otro problema al quitar el if, no se me respeta que por cada id hay una cantidad se me guarda el total de todas las cantidades en cada producto del carrito si me puedes ayudar como controlar eso gracias de nuevo

Comment: Por que no al finalizar el ciclo pones la $cantidad = 0 o igual quitan el 1 + en la siguiente linea $cantidad = $item['qty'];

Comment: Gracias de nuevo si se acodo con tus indicaciones

Comment: En estos casos deberias de abrir una nueva pregunta para que se te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

En lo personal pienso que es mejor hacer un insert de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO xtabla (id,nombre,edad) VALUES ";
$x = 0;
$total = count($array);
foreach($array as $value){
  $query .= "(null,'".$value['nombre']."','".$value['edad']."')";
  $x++;
  if( $x < $total ){
    $query .= ",";
  }
}

$resultado = $conexion->query($query);
return $resultado;
```

De esta forma harias un INSERT de x cantidad de datos en un solo query y seria mucho mas rapido.